# Wordpress "search engine friendly" urls ( permalinks) implementation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I had the pleasure to take a peak at Wordpress source code; i was wondering how they managed the custom url feature, but i couldn't really get it.

The rewrite rules inside wordpress .htaccess file simply redirect all requests to index.php.

After that, it's a mystery to me: how do they make `example.com/this/title/is/cool/` match `index.php?p=233 ?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once it's redirected to index.php, that file can look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine what is in the `this/title/is/cool` portion, and then go look up what page to serve from a database, since the REQUEST_URI lists the full URI string, even though the actual page url that was redirected to is only the first portion of it.

For instance,

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar/
```

gets rewritten to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/foo/bar/
```

This will actually result in http://www.example.com/index.php being loaded, but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will have the full `/index.php/foo/bar/` within it.

Some apps use a different approach, they use `.htaccess` to just take the trailing "directories" and put them into the query string, so that the rewrite becomes something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?path=/foo/bar/
```

in which case the supplied path is available in `_GET['path']`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it could be something like that but denied it as i thought no one can be certain server variables are available everywhere. 

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is actually a reliable variable, that is present on all setups?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` does not contain the full URI but only the URI path and query.

Comment: @pixeline: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is provided by the web server to PHP; most common web servers (including Apache and IIS) support it.